# Reason for no change in electrode potential in reference electrodes

Tags: electrochemistry, analytical-chemistry

Reference electrodes such as the saturated calomel electrode and silver chloride electrode have a constant potential because the $\ce{Cl-}$ concentration (or, to be more precise, the activity) is constant.
The semi-reaction for those electrodes are:

$$\ce{Hg2Cl2 + 2e- <=> 2Hg + 2Cl-}$$

$$\ce{AgCl + e- <=> Ag + Cl-}$$

Now, since chloride ions are produced (or consumed, when the electrode is an anode) from the half-reactions, how is it possible that their concentration remains constant?

Is the quantity of chloride produced or consumed is negligible compared to that coming from the $\ce{KCl}$ dissociation?

Comment: Current flow through a reference electrode is supposed to be negligible, i.e., pA or less. The chloride ion concentration is significantly high or there is excess solid (containing the chloride ions). So there is negligible change in chloride ion concentration when the reference electrode is used as designed.

Comment: Your last sentence answered your own question. If you want a simple example, assume a current of 1 pA flowing for 10000 seconds. Multiply those, divide by the Faraday constant, and the resulting tiny numerical value shows that chloride ion concentration change is negligible in any reasonable reference cell solution volume.